# How to send messages to my client applications using c#

Tags: c#, winforms, message

I have created an application.

I usually make changes in my application.

But the people who had taken my application need to know that i have updated in my

application.

I cant call everyone and say that i have updated my application and can u please download

it from my website.

I want to give messages to my clients applications using c#.

I dont know how can i send it and how can they receive it.

There would be a great appreciation if someone colud help me.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create one table with newest version of app in the database (if your app is using it, if not - a file, like XML, is enough), and make your application to check on load, if user version is lower that one from database. If so: display info with link, that "new version is available, please download it from ..."

Comment: Can u please give an example because i dont know about messaging

Comment: Here is an example of how to read data from XML file over network. Your code would be much simpler in step 8/9. [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307643) If talking about database connection - it depends DB system you're using, but it's a normal query, like `"SELECT last_version FROM tbl_info"`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably put you app on the web for download right? Then put also version file too.

Your app can compare the online version file with its version automatically, and then notify the user or download newer version automatically.

```
static public class Deployment
{
    public static readonly string WebSite = @"....";
    public const string version_filename = "version";

    static string get_version(Stream stream)
    {
        var lines = new List<string>();

        var reader = new StreamReader(stream);

        while (true)
        {
            var s = reader.ReadLine();
            if (s == null)
                break;

            lines.Add(s);
        }

        stream.Close();

        return lines.Join(CHAR.LineFeed).Trim();
    }
    static string GetWebVersionInfo()
    {
        try
        {
            var client = new WebClient();
            using (var stream = client.OpenRead(WebSite + version_filename))
                return get_version(stream);
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
    static string GetLocalVersionInfo()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var stream = new FileStream(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(ProgramInfo.FilePath) +
                                               System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar +
                                               version_filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                return get_version(stream);
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
    static public bool IsNewVersionAvailable()
    {
        var web_version = Deployment.GetWebVersionInfo();
        var exe_version = Deployment.GetLocalVersionInfo(); 

        return (web_version != null && (exe_version == null || exe_version.Comparison(web_version) == CompareEnum.Less));
    }

}
```

**It won't compile right away** because some trivial symbols are missing here, but you have idea I hope.

Comment: Yes you are right! but Can u please give some examples because i dont know about messaging